# I don't know how to simulate input stop in C++

Tags: c++, io

So I have program, which loads grades, for each student and outputs the name and the final grade. It is program from Accelerated C++ book and I found a problem, where I don't know how to simulate stopping an input.

###### Example of input:

```
Harry 98 58 78 56 98 78 58 58
```

, then I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and another student will be read, so I write:

```
Jack 88 54 33 89 54 67 15 78
```

Now I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and would like to stop reading students and see the output, but how I can do this without some another condition in a program. I read some articles about `EOF`, but when I was trying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, this just doesn't seem to work.

---

## Code

### main.cpp

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "grade.h"
#include "student_info.h"

using namespace std;


int main() {
    vector<Student_info> students;
    Student_info record;
    string::size_type maxlen = 0;


    while (read(cin, record)) {
        maxlen = max(maxlen, record.name.size());
        students.push_back(record);
    }

    sort(students.begin(), students.end(), compare);

    for (vector<Student_info>::size_type i = 0;
        i = !students.size(); ++i) {

        cout << students[i].name
            << string(maxlen + 1 - students[i].name.size(), ' ');

        try {
            double final_grade = grade(students[i]);
            streamsize prec = cout.precision();
            cout << setprecision(3) << final_grade
                << setprecision(prec);
        }
        catch (domain_error e) {
            cout << e.what();
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### grade.h

```
#ifndef GUARD_grade_h
#define GUARD_grade_h

#include <vector>
#include "student_info.h"

double grade(double, double, double);
double grade(double, double, const std::vector<double>&);
double grade(const Student_info &);

#endif // !GUARD_grade_h
```

#### grade.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "median.h"
#include "student_info.h"
#include "grade.h"

using std::domain_error; using std::vector;

double grade(double midterm, double final, double homeworks) 
{
    return 0.2 * midterm + 0.4 * final + 0.4 * homeworks;
}

double grade(double midterm, double final, const vector<double> &hm)
{
    if (hm.size() == 0)
        throw domain_error("student has done no homework");
    return grade(midterm, final, median(hm));
}

double grade(const Student_info& s)
{
    return grade(s.midterm, s.final, s.homework);
}
```

###### student_info.h

```
#ifndef GUARD_student_info_h
#define GUARD_student_info_h

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Student_info {
    std::string name;
    double midterm, final;
    std::vector<double> homework;
};

bool compare(const Student_info&, const Student_info&);
std::istream& read(std::istream&, Student_info&);
std::istream& read_hw(std::istream&, std::vector<double>&);

#endif // !GUARD_student_info_h
```

###### student_info.cpp

```
#include "student_info.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::istream;     using std::vector;

bool compare(const Student_info& x, const Student_info& y) {
    return x.name < y.name;
}

istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hm) {
    if (in) {
        //get rid of previous contents
        hm.clear();

        //read homework grades
        double x;
        while (in >> x)
            hm.push_back(x);
        //clear the stream so that input will work for the next student
        in.clear();
    }
    return in;
}

istream& read(istream& is, Student_info& s) {
    
    is >> s.name >> s.midterm >> s.final;

    read_hw(is, s.homework);
    return is;
}
```

###### median.h

```
#ifndef GUARD_median_h
#define GUARD_median_h

#include <vector>
double median(std::vector<double>);

#endif
```

###### median.cpp

```
#include "median.h"
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

using std::domain_error;    using std::sort;    using std::vector;

double median(vector<double> vec) {
    typedef vector<double>::size_type vc_sz;
    vc_sz size = vec.size();
    if (size == 0)
        throw domain_error("median of an empty vector");

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    vc_sz mid = size / 2;

    return size % 2 == 0 ? (vec[mid] + vec[mid - 1]) / 2
        : vec[mid];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass `EOF` you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

If that does not do the job, you may want to consider introducing a *"stop strings"*. You will check for one on every start of new input series. In general it is of the following form:

```
if (input_string != stop_string) 
    /* continue further */;
else 
    /* stop getting input */;
```

So, you can look toward the following approach. We left loop in the `main.cpp` untouched, it still iterates over the input stream returned by `read()`. We manage the reading logic in the `read()` and return the input stream with `eofbit` set if the input was commanded to be stopped:

```
istream& read(istream& is, Student_info& s) {
    // I added this print for clarity of tests
    std::cout << "Enter name, midterm, final (or 'stop'): " << '\n';
    std::string current_input;
    is >> current_input;
    if (current_input != "stop") { // If not `stop`, then it is a name
        s.name = current_input;
        is >> s.midterm >> s.final; // Get input further
    } else { // We hit `stop`, set EOF, return
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::eofbit);
        return is;
    }
    read_hw(is, s.homework);
    return is;
}
```

There's a second loop, out of which there's no suggested exit, in the `read_hw()` function:

```
//read homework grades
double x;
while (in >> x) { // While we have valid input...
    hm.push_back(x);
}
```

You can stop this one by inputting a non-numeric value. But you may also consider introducing a "stop character" here as well. Like this:

```
//read homework grades
double x;
while (in >> x) {
    if (x == -1) // If a user inputs -1, we stop looping
        break;
    hm.push_back(x);
}
```

Comment: So this problem, I solve, but code still wont work. It will output nothing. I found one problem in grade.h . The second function: `double grade(double, double, const std::vector<double>&); . ` Visual Studio keep saying that the function definition can not be found, but the definition for this function is in the grade.cpp.

Comment: I found the mistake. It was in for loop at Main.cpp . I write i = !students.size() so the for loop never turn on.  When I  correct it, it finally works like expected. Thank you very much for the input help @rawrex .